# condicional de excel

Tags: formato-condicional

Estoy intentando realizar una operación u otra en excel dependiendo de una parte del texto que aparezca en una celda. Así, si tengo  botas enteras aparecerá la palabra "bota" en la celda A4, si por el contrario son medias botas tenemos dos opciones, que sean de la marca BOHOR o no, en cuyo caso, si son BOHOR hace una operación y si no lo son hará otra.

La función que he creado es la siguiente (un condicional anidado)

```
=SI(A4="bota*";I6/(D6*500);SI(A4="BOHOR media*";I6/(D6*225);I6/(D6*250)))
```

No me funciona ya que siempre me da el resultado de la operación `I6/(D6*250)`, caso en que no es bota y no es de la marca BOHOR. No paro de darle vueltas y no lo consigo. Podéis ayudarme?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Estás intentando hacer algo que Excel no permite. Le dices que la celda A4 tenga por contenido el texto "bota*". Excel interpreta este texto como literal, incluido el "*", que no lo considera un comodín.

Probablemente encuentres otras soluciones. La que propongo te funcionará. Se trata de utilizar la función `HALLAR` que te permite saber si encuentra la palabra buscada, devolviendo un número, si no la encuentra devuelve `#VALUE!`. Si la combinas con la función `ESNUMERO` podrás saber si la encuentra.

Quedaría así:

```
=SI(ESNUMERO(HALLAR("bota";A4));I6/(D6*500);SI(ESNUMERO(HALLAR("BOHOR media";A4));I6/(D6*225);I6/(D6*250)))
```

Si tienes "bota" en la A4, la función `=HALLAR("bota";A4)` devuelve un número y lo podemos comprobar con `=ESNUMERO(HALLAR("bota";A3)))` que devuelve `VERDADERO`, que te sirve para la función `SI`.

Comment: Muchísima gracias Roger, tu indicación me va genial. Funciona!! Lo único que yo creía que "*" lo consideraba Excel como comodín. Debo indagar más en este programa, se pueden hacer maravillas con él. Muchísima gracias